# PHP DAO Letting users befriend eachother (technically)

Tags: php, oop, dao

Let's say I have users who can befriend eachother, technically, how do I solve this using DAO in PHP?

Database:

```
users       |  user_friends
- userid    |  - userid_user1
- username  |  - userid_user2
```

PHP User object:

```
class User
{
  private $userid;
  private $username;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Should I use this method to befriend users:

```
$u1 = UserDAO::getInstance()->findUserById(1);
$u2 = UserDAO::getInstance()->findUserById(2);

UserDAO::getInstance()->befriendUsers($u1, $u2);
```

OR should I use this method:

```
$u1 = UserDAO::getInstance()->findUserById(1);
$u2 = UserDAO::getInstance()->findUserById(2);
$u1->befriend($u2);

// befriend method would look like this in the User object
public function befriend(User $u)
{
  UserDAO::getInstance()->befriend($this, $u);
}
```

Or maybe another way?

Comment: As @MikeSW says, this isn’t the role of a Data Access Object. A DAO should map objects in your application and persist them to a data store (database, file etc). It shouldn’t contain any business logic like befriending users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, none. UserDAO deals with User but not with user relationships, which is a different concern.

To keep it simple, you should have another FriendsDao which will care about the friendships. Of course, you need to update the friendships when an user is deleted.

Comment: So the FriendsDAO has a method which accepts two User objects and then saves a record to the user_friends database table in this case?

Comment: Also, the UserDAO::getInstance()->findUserById(1) method, which returns an User object, is a task for the DAO?